# MicroBlaze Interrupt Handler Not Called

Tags: c++, embedded, verilog, driver, mouse

I want to capture mouse movement packets in an embedded system receiving packets of data from an input mouse (initialized in ps/2 mode).   How do I get my exception handler to get called?  The interrupt handler is never triggered.     I set up my processor to run with external interrupts and  connected only one signal to the processor's interrupt input port, and I do not use an interrupt controller.  To capture input movements, I use a software based circular buffer.

Please help.

```
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "xil_exception.h"
#include "ps2_core.h"

Ps2Core::Ps2Core(uint32_t core_base_addr) {
   base_addr = core_base_addr;
   registerCallback();
}

Ps2Core::~Ps2Core() {
}

void Ps2Core::enqueue(unsigned char value) {
    if ((tail + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE == head) {
    // queue is full, do nothing
    return;
    }
    queue[tail] = value;
    queueCount++;
    tail = (tail + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
}

unsigned char Ps2Core::dequeue(void) {
    if (head == tail) {
    // queue is empty, do nothing
    return 0;
    }
    unsigned char value = queue[head];
    queueCount--;
    head = (head + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
    return value;
}

void Ps2Core::handleInterrupt(Ps2Core *ps2) {
    uint8_t byte;
    byte = ps2->rx_byte();
    ps2->enqueue(byte);
}


void Ps2Core::registerCallback(){
    Xil_ExceptionInit();
    Xil_ExceptionRegisterHandler(XIL_EXCEPTION_ID_INT,
                                    (Xil_ExceptionHandler)handleInterrupt,
                                    this);
    Xil_ExceptionEnable();
}

int Ps2Core::get_mouse_activity(int *lbtn, int *rbtn, int *xmov,
      int *ymov, int *zmov) {
   uint8_t b1, b2, b3, b4;

   uint32_t tmp;

   /* retrieve bytes only if 4 or a multiple of 4 exist in queue */
   if (queueCount >= 4) {
       b1 = dequeue();
       b2 = dequeue();
       b3 = dequeue();
       b4 = dequeue();
   }
   else
       return (0);
   /* extract button info */
   *lbtn = (int) (b1 & 0x01);      // extract bit 0
   *rbtn = (int) (b1 & 0x02) >> 1; // extract bit 1
   /* extract x movement; manually convert 9-bit 2's comp to int */
   tmp = (uint32_t) b2;
   if (b1 & 0x10)                // check MSB (sign bit) of x movement
      tmp = tmp | 0xffffff00;    // manual sign-extension if negative
   *xmov = (int) tmp;            // data conversion
   /* extract y movement; manually convert 9-bit 2's comp to int */
   tmp = (uint32_t) b3;
   if (b1 & 0x20)                // check MSB (sign bit) of y movement
      tmp = tmp | 0xffffff00;    // manual sign-extension if negative
   *ymov = (int) tmp;            // data conversion
   tmp = (uint32_t) b4;
   if (b4 & 0x08)               // check MSB (sign bit) of z movement
      tmp = tmp | 0xfffffff0;   // manual sign-extension if negative
   *zmov = (int) tmp;           // data conversion
   /* success */
   return (1);
}
```

**Module Instances**

```
//instantiate uBlaze MCS
       cpu cpu_unit (
        .Clk(clk_100M),                          
        .Reset(reset),            
        .IO_addr_strobe(io_addr_strobe),    
        .IO_address(io_address),            
        .IO_byte_enable(io_byte_enable),    
        .IO_read_data(io_read_data),        
        .IO_read_strobe(io_read_strobe),    
        .IO_ready(io_ready),                
        .IO_write_data(io_write_data),      
        .IO_write_strobe(io_write_strobe),
        .INTC_Interrupt(interrupt)
        );
    

   // instantiated i/o subsystem
   mmio_sys_sampler_arty_a7  mmio_unit (
    .clk(clk_100M),
    .reset(reset),
    .mmio_cs(fp_mmio_cs),
    .mmio_wr(fp_wr),
    .mmio_rd(fp_rd),
    .mmio_addr(fp_addr), 
    .mmio_wr_data(fp_wr_data),
    .mmio_rd_data(fp_rd_data),
    .rx_done_tick(interrupt),
    .ps2d_in(ps2d_in),
    .ps2c_in(ps2c_in),
    .tri_c(tri_c),
    .tri_d(tri_d),
    .ps2c_out(ps2c_out),
    .ps2d_out(ps2d_out),          
    .rx(rx),
    .tx(tx)
   );
```

EDIT - Latest GIST Code (Interrupt not triggered, from rx_done_tick signal input to INTC_Interrupt)

See:
https://gist.github.com/vahejab/e8950b2efaf5f9376ffbdcefbbdc4ee3

Comment: Please note, interrupt comes from a signal from a module that goes to value of 1 when receiving of a byte of data from input mouse is completed.   I use that value to send to the processor directly as a pulse to indicate that I received data, so that I can ideally call my interrupt handler (callback).  It doesn't work though.  Any help would be appreciated to shed light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the port names, it looks like you have an interrupt controller in your 'cpu' module. But I don't see any code configuring that--instead it's connecting directly to the MicroBlaze CPU's exception handler. Xilinx's driver for the interrupt controller should be attaching itself to the exception handler and your code should be connecting to it via `register_int_handler` / `enable_interrupt`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  I tried to use axi interrupt controller.  But I don’t have an axi bus.  So I relied upon the output tick signal from the custom module as input to my intrerrupt.  I used microblaze mcs and checkmarked enable external interrupts as level sensitive positive edge and asynchronous.   Is this the way to proceed? CPU is the microblaze code from Xilinx.  I used the verilog wrapper.  There’s an irq port out of microblaze but that’s output.   I don’t connect to that port.

Comment: In that case, maybe the issue is the level-sensitive setting. In that mode, you need to keep the interrupt line asserted until the handler runs, and then it needs to set a register on your module to tell it to deassert. If your output tick signal is more like a pulse, try the edge-sensitive setting. And make sure the pulse is long enough for the CPU to see it.

Comment: Also in my inner microblaze instance. I see the unconnected interrupt address but I can’t connect to it I have it read only.  And I use microblaze mcs.  So I only can connect to the outside wrapper ports. I will try to increase pulse duration and sensitivity settings.   I’ll report back once done.

Comment: That's for fast interrupt mode. You don't need it for normal mode. Just make sure to change the configuration to edge-sensitive.

Comment: I was able to modify the code to use the GPIO input as a connection to the interrupt pulse.  However, interrupt is never handled.  No syntax, debug or linking errors, mouse initializes but never is generating an interrupt.  Any observations?

Comment: I haven't used Xilinx's GPIO module so not sure about that.

Comment: Even though I commented these out, since I am trying polling, I had better luck with microblaze_register_handler(XIOModule_DeviceInterruptHandler,XPAR_IOMODULE_0_DEVICE_ID); microblaze_enable_interrupts(); rather than register_int_handler(), enable_interrupts(), since I could not include xintc.h or some necessary library for these functions.

Comment: Since I don't have direct GPIO ports in my VC707 board, I have to use XIOModule which is the only applicable driver visible in my Board Support Package, I understand now why I could not get GPIO module to work.  I connected a GPIO AXI module to my MicroBlaze so that I can generate an appropriate interrupt signal.  If that does not work I will directly connect the source of the pulse signal to my MicroBlaze instance GPIO tri input and interrupt input.  But for now, I use the GPIO module with a XIOModule.  I tried XIOModule_DiscreteWrite(&ps2->gpi, XGPIO_0_CHANNEL, 0); but It doesn't clear

Comment: Can you look at my edited code to see if I'm doing this right? The interrupt handler is still not called when I receive a byte from the mouse.  My oscilloscope shows an interrupt tick on byte received.

Comment: I don't see a call to Xil_ExceptionEnable in the new code.

Comment: I ended up reverting to polling and looping wait in my second most recent link.  First link is my attempt at interrupt at its best version but unsuccessful, I could not enable exceptions for some reason as it was greyed out in the library (#define was not present in xparameters.h)
https://github.com/vahejab/arty_sv_sampler/blob/742d78b2c552ea0e3168de48d43858edc89eadcb/arty_sv_sampler.sdk/VC707_Application/src/ps2_core.cpp
------------Interrupt Version
https://github.com/vahejab/arty_sv_sampler/blob/main/arty_sv_sampler.sdk/VC707_Application/src/ps2_core.cpp
------------Busy Wait Version

Comment: In xil_exception.c  MICROBLAZE_EXCEPTIONS_ENABLED was never defined, after importing the hardware and creating a BSP (I had to even try to turn on exceptions in system.mss to no avail) I couldn't use the exception handler so I figured it wasn't possible that is why it's not there.   Interrupts didn't work directly either.  So I was left with GPIO which was not doing anything different than polling so I switched to polling.
`void Xil_ExceptionEnable(void)
{
#ifdef MICROBLAZE_EXCEPTIONS_ENABLED
 microblaze_enable_exceptions();
#endif
 microblaze_enable_interrupts();
}`

Comment: I updated the code and created a gist, still does not trigger the ISR, so I do not really know what I am missing